# SQL - Cannot find either column "c" or user-defined function or aggregate "c" or the name is ambiguos

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not really good in SQL and I did some searching and couldn't really figured it out how to use STUFF. I mean it looks simple but when I use it, there's always an error.

Anyway, here is the portion of my code and I just want to combine 2 printer of the rows with the same computer name pulled from database, honestly I'm not even sure if I'm doing it right but please do correct me if I'm wrong. Really need the professionals to guide me and do let me know if the information is not sufficient. Thanks in advance.

Update:

Added more code, and I didn't mention clearly, my query is pulling different data from multiple tables. It may be a bit messy but it got what I wanted, my problem is combining the printer result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sc.ComputerName AS 'Computer name',
*
*
*
ISNULL(c.PrinterName <-- error on this c.printername
(
STUFF
        ((
            SELECT 
                '; ' + c.PrinterName 
                FROM PrinterList AS c
                WHERE c.ComputerName = sc.ComputerName
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2,'')), '') AS 'Printer' 

FROM Computer sc 
Full Join PCInfo AS a 
ON a.ComputerName = sc.ComputerName
Full Join DriverList AS b 
ON b.ComputerName = sc.ComputerName 
Full Join PrinterList AS c 
ON c.ComputerName = sc.ComputerName 
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(lower(sc.ComputerName), ' ',''))) like '%example%'
```

Comment: Perhaps it's due to the same `c` alias being designated in both your `STUFF` and your `FULL JOIN`, thus the ambiguity. I may be incorrect on that though.

Comment: Post your real query, please. It looks like you have some misplaced parentheses and possibly other typos.

Comment: Updated my code

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1):

The c alias is only available in the namespace of the subquery, but you do not reference it from there.

Comment: What is your suggestion or changes to make this sql work? I think the STUFF part should be working.....

Comment: @Zephyros I struggle a bit reading the STUFF statement, but actually it should be enough to replace ISNULL(c.PrinterName... with ISNULL(Printer...

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT c.PrinterName,
       STUFF( (SELECT '; ' + c.PrinterName 
               FROM PrinterList AS c
               WHERE c.ComputerName = sc.ComputerName
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'
                     ), 1, 2, '')
             ) as printers 
FROM computer c ;
```

There is no need for the `join` in the outer query.  I also don't see why an `outer join` would be desired.